# Как сохранить ID вместо NAME

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сохранить ID вместо NAME в запрос?
Имеется две таблицы с пользователем и подразделением.
При выводе формы в WPF показываю имя подразделения, но нужно сохранить его id в запрос вместо namedivision

Код вывода в Combobox подразделения

```
        void fill_division()
    {
        MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM division", mySqlConnection);
            MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string namedivision = dr.GetString(1);
                division.Items.Add(namedivision);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.Source.ToString(), MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
                mySqlConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Код добавления нового пользователя

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondname.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(middlename.Text)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(datebirth.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(gender.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(division.Text))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, secondname, datebirth, gender, iddivision, middlename) VALUES (@firstname, @secondname, @datebirth, @gender, @iddivision, @middlename)";
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, mySqlConnection);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("secondname", secondname.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", firstname.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("middlename", middlename.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("datebirth", datebirth.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", gender.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("iddivision", division.Text);

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mySqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно так `division.SelectedIndex` но это не `id` из базы, а просто индекс элемента в комбобоксе.